# How to read complete file with bitstring

Tags: python, bitstring, bitstream

I want to read as many 24 bit chunks as possible from a file.
How can I do this using bitstrings' **ConstBitStream**
when I don't now how many chunks there are?

Currently I do this:

```
eventList = ConstBitStream(filename = 'events.dat')
for i in range(1000) :
    packet = eventList.read(24)
```

(here I have to calculate the number of events beforehand)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could read until an ReadError exeption is generated

```
try:
    while True:
        packet = eventList.read(24)
except ReadError:
    pass
```

Comment: `ReadError` is a `bitstring` exception. It has to be either imported from `bitstring` or used as `bitstring.ReadError`.

Answer (score 3):

Catching the `ReadError` is a perfectly good answer, but another way is to instead use the [cut](http://packages.python.org/bitstring/constbitarray.html?highlight=cut#bitstring.Bits.cut) method, which returns a generator for bitstrings of a given length, so just

```
for packet in eventList.cut(24):
```

should work.